# What should I do when a Delphi code example doesn't compile?

Tags: api, delphi, changelog

Here is a code sample I downloaded from http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0104_4.htm

```
procedure WBLoadHTML(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; HTMLCode: string) ;
var
   sl: TStringList;
   ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
   WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank') ;
   while WebBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

   if Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then
   begin
     sl := TStringList.Create;
     try
       ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         sl.Text := HTMLCode;
         sl.SaveToStream(ms) ;
         ms.Seek(0, 0) ;
         (WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(ms)) ;
       finally
         ms.Free;
       end;
     finally
       sl.Free;
     end;
   end;
end;
```

I am using RAD Studio XE5 and the compiler is complaining about the ReadyState and Document properties of the WebBrowser instance.

So, in the Java world, where I come from, when some API feature is deprecated by the Java Gods, they make reference in the API to what I should be doing instead.

This does not appear to happen in the Delphi world. The ReadyState and Document properties of the TWebBrowser class have simply been removed from the API.

I am sure someone here can whip this code into shape. However, I need to find the general solution to the problem of changing Delphi APIs. This isn't the first time I've encountered this.

Another example is that TButton used to have a property called Caption, that is now called Text. That one I had to guess for myself.

So I guess what I am looking for is a Delphi API changelog, preferably available online...

Where can I find such a thing?

Comment: Regarding TButton : You are probably using FIREMONKEY now, not the VCL.  VCL TButton is a different TButton than the FMX one. You are like the Java guy who switches from AWT to SWING and then is confused because things moved and changed.   I believe your confusion is beyond that which a changelog can correct. Try reading the fine documentation!

Comment: The best thing to do with that code is to bin it. It stinks. On many levels.

Comment: Warren, How can I tell if a code snippet is using VCL or Firemonkey? In Java the AWT button is called Button and the Swing button is called JButton. I would argue that if you go to the trouble of naming things the same, it is not unreasonable to expect them to behave the same.

Comment: Try to use TChromium instead https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/ it used Chrome instead of IE which is used by TWebBrowser.

Comment: Uses Vcl.Forms? It's VCL. Uses Fmx.Forms, its Firemonkey. Have you heard of Namespaces, Dear Experienced Java User?  :-) Think of Uses as being the Delphi equivalent of an import statement in some other language, except that when I use a unit, I'm actually not creating a namespace, I'm actually polluting my unit's local namespace. So Delphi doesn't have namespaces, it has unit scopes.  However, the awareness of this fact, would be enough to make clear what your Uses clause is Using, therefore, the TButton you are using is not the same TButton.

Comment: Of course I've heard of namespaces. I think you're missing my point. Code snippets on the internet rarely include marginalia like import statements and uses clauses. The example I gave originally doesn't mention VCL anywhere, nor should it have to. But giving similar-but-different classes the same name (regardless of namespaces) is a code smell.

Comment: @User, back in the days when this article was written there was **only** VCL. and it was good. :)

Comment: How about we've learned that random code googling does not teach us a new platform, and sometimes we have to read the manual?

Comment: I'd LOVE a manual. Do you know where I could find one?

Answer (score 4):

This code sample is designed for a VCL application. You've clearly placed it into an FMX application. Solve the problem by switching to a VCL application.

That said, I am not able to recommend this code. It performs a busy wait on the web browser control! And it includes a call to the much maligned, and rightly so, `Application.ProcessMessages`. That busy loop is just waiting until the document has finished loading. And the component provides an event that fires when that happens, namely [`DocumentComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When a code example doesn't compile, I read the messages from the compiler and check that I've included the right units in the `uses` clause. Sometimes I refer to the documentation, and in extreme cases I will do a grep search for a particular library file, or just ask the Delphi Gods on SO if I'm feeling particularly sadistic on that day.